Model Can't Predict Correctly Even Though Has A Good Classification Report
I have tried to run this model from the link:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexfordna/garbage-classification-mobilenetv2-92-accuracy/notebook
When I did it on colab with similar dataset (but smaller, 2100 img to 6 classes), it works well. But when I added this code to predict the input image:
from google.colab import files
from PIL import Image


def process_uploaded_image(image_path, target_size=(224, 224)):
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    img = img.resize(target_size)  
    img_array = np.array(img) 

    if img_array.shape[-1] == 4:  
        img_array = img_array[..., :3]

    img_array = img_array / 255.0 
    img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)  
    img_array = mobilenetv2.preprocess_input(img_array) 

    return img_array

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():  
    processed_image = process_uploaded_image(fn, target_size=IMAGE_SIZE)    
    preds = model.predict(processed_image)
    pred_class = np.argmax(preds, axis=1)
  
    plt.imshow(Image.open(fn))  # Display the uploaded image
    plt.title(f'Predicted class: {categories[pred_class[0]]}')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
    print(f'File {fn} is predicted as: {categories[pred_class[0]]}')

The result is a wrong prediction. For example, the model always predict my input as a "trash" class. It will change to another class when I stop the runtime, but it still in a wrong prediction too.
I also added this code to check the prediction probabilities:
preds = model.predict(processed_image)
pred_probs = preds[0]  # Get the prediction probabilities for the first (and only) batch
print("Prediction probabilities:", pred_probs)
pred_class = np.argmax(pred_probs)
print("Predicted class:", categories[pred_class])

the output:
**1/1** ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ **0s** 24ms/step Prediction probabilities: \[0.31027108 0.12315894 0.47848797 0.00863316 0.07789086 0.00155797\]   
Predicted class: metal  

Why is this happening, and how can my model predict the result correctly?

You are probably not preprocessing images exactly as the model was trained, for example you are applying mobilenetv2.preprocess_input while the model already does this, so its being done twice.

Thanks for the advice! I've changed the code and it works!

Sometimes it will work but most of the it wont work
